# Sort list view with Folders and Files types alphabetically in andorid

Tags: android, sorting, listview

Sort list view with Folders and Files alphabetically

I am trying the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private File file;
    private List<String> myList;
    private ListView listView;
    private TextView pathTextView;
    private String mediapath = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

    private final static String[] acceptedExtensions= {"mp3", "mp2",    "wav", "flac", "ogg", "au" , "snd", "mid", "midi", "kar"
        , "mga", "aif", "aiff", "aifc", "m3u", "oga", "spx"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.pathlist);
        pathTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);

        myList = new ArrayList<String>();   

        String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        Log.e("Root",root_sd);

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        File list[] = null ;
        /* if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state) ) {  // we can read the External Storage...
            list=getAllFilesOfDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        }*/

        pathTextView.setText(root_sd);

        file = new File( root_sd ) ;       
        list = file.listFiles(new AudioFilter());
        Log.e("Size of list ","" +list.length);
        //LoadDirectory(root_sd);

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {

            String name=list[i].getName();
        int count =     getAudioFileCount(list[i].getAbsolutePath());
       Log.e("Count : "+count, list[i].getAbsolutePath());
       if(count!=0)
       myList.add(name);
            /*int count=getAllFilesOfDir(list[i]);
            Log.e("Songs count ",""+count);

            */  

        }


        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                File temp_file = new File( file, myList.get( position ) );  

                if( !temp_file.isFile())        
                {
                    //LoadDirectory(myList.get( position ));

                    file = new File( file, myList.get( position ));
                    File list[] = file.listFiles(new AudioFilter());

                    myList.clear();

                    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
                    {
                        String name=list[i].getName();

                        int count =     getAudioFileCount(list[i].getAbsolutePath());
                           Log.e("Count : "+count, list[i].getAbsolutePath());
                           if(count!=0)
                          myList.add(name);
                        /*int count=getAllFilesOfDir(list[i]);
                        Log.e("Songs count ",""+count);
                        if(count!=0)
                            myList.add(name);*/
                    }

                    pathTextView.setText( file.toString());
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));

                }


            }
        });



    }
```

It gives me the files and folders for all songs

Howevever ,If a  folder contains both sub folders and songs ,I want to sort the listview to show all sub folders first and then all the songs in that folder

How can this be done

Comment: how you are differentiating file and folders

Comment: it checks temp_file for folder or file `if( !temp_file.isFile()) `

Comment: it will enter in this if condition if it is folder?, so what about file?

Answer (score 1):

use this function

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

add this line before **setAdapter**.

it will sort your String Arraylist in Alphabet order.

Comment: yes but how do we sort to show only folders first then files in same listview

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to sort:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
});
```